# How to do something else at the end of an iteration

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

I have a list that contains some strings , I want to add some predefined values before every string in a list but the value at the end of the iteration should be different

Here is the list

```py
lst = ['USER_INVITE','USER_LEAVE','GIVEAWAY_START','GIVEAWAY_EDIT','USER_INVITE','USER_LEAVE']
```

the expected output is

```
<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399> USER_INVITE
<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399> USER_LEAVE
<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399> GIVEAWAY_START
<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399> GIVEAWAY_EDIT
<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399> USER_INVITE
<:878677686350934027:910454682219085834> USER_LEAVE
```

here you can see the value before `USER_LEAVE` is different than others

I can simply do something like this to put these values before strings without a loop

```py
logs = '<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>\n'.join(map(str,keys[I]))
```

maybe iteration will help in this case by doing something else at the end of the loop

Comment: yes iteration will help, what is the question?

Comment: the question is how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using iteration, and some control flow logic around identifying the last item in the list, this can be done as follows:

```
output_str = ""

for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    if i == len(lst) - 1:  # Logic for identifying the last element
        prefix = '<:878677686350934027:910454682219085834>'
    else:  # If not the last element in the list, do this:
         prefix = '<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>'
    
    output_str += f'{prefix} {item}\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
output_str = ""

for item in lst[:-1]:
    output_str += f'<:878677686350934027:910454682219085834> {item}\n'
output_str += f'<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399> {lst[-1]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just work on every key but the last and then combine the output at the end.

```
a = "\n".join('<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>' + key for key in lst[:-1])
b = '<:878677686350934027:910454682219085834>' + lst[-1]
a + b

'<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>USER_INVITE\n<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>USER_LEAVE\n<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>GIVEAWAY_START\n<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>GIVEAWAY_EDIT\n<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>USER_INVITE<:878677686350934027:910454682219085834>USER_LEAVE'
```